# Вызов метода родительского класса для полей дочернего

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть несколько классов `Class1`, `Class2` и у них у всех есть метод `get_params()`.
Для них я описал интерфейс `Main_class` и через конструктор их создаю с одним интерфейсом.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Main_class(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def init(self, x, y):
        pass

    ...


class Class1():

    def get_params():        
    ...
```

Мне не хочется в каждом дочернем классе описывать один и тот же метод. Могу я как то его описать для родительского класса, так чтобы он вызывался для полей дочернего класса?

PS

Задача по сути учебная и связи с реальностью не имеет, просто разбираюсь в работе языка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Трюк в том, что в каждом методе первый параметр `self` означает текущий объект, вызывавший данный метод.

Соответственно, когда мы пишем, например, `self.abc`, то считаем что у объекта, вызвавшего метод есть такое поле:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Main_class(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def init(self, x, y):
        pass

    def get_params(self):
        return self.abc, self.foo


class Class1(Main_class):
    def __init__(self):
        self.abc = 1
        self.foo = 'foo'

    def init(self, x, y):
        pass


obj = Class1()
print(obj.get_params())  # (1, 'foo')
```

Comment: Это не совсем то. Я хочу в родительском классе описать метод, и не описывать его в дочернем. При этом при вызове этого метода, я хочу вернуть поля дочернего класса(всегда одни и  теже)

Comment: @Viktorov, можете (но это не очевидно), обновил ответ